# Vim / Neovim PlantUML Preview didn't work

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin

Environment

- macOS Ventura on M1
- iTerm2
- Homebrew
- Google Chrome

I have tried to install a PlantUML-Preview in (Neo)Vim with this [plantuml-previewer.vim](https://github.com/weirongxu/plantuml-previewer.vim) plugin.

There are described some dependencies:
Java -> I've done `brew install java`
Graphviz -> I've done `brew install graphviz`
On [PlantUML home](https://plantuml.com/) they have information about the [Graphviz installation](https://plantuml.com/graphviz-dot) where they say, the dot executable is expected in `/usr/local/bin/dot`. I do `which dot` with the result `/opt/homebrew/bin/dot`.
So I've done a symlink with `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/dot /usr/local/bin/dot` with the result in `/usr/local/bin/dot`: `dot -> /opt/homebrew/bin/dot`.
After that, I've follow the instructions on [plantuml-previewer.vim](https://github.com/weirongxu/plantuml-previewer.vim) again and put the rest to my `.vimrc`:

```
    Plug 'aklt/plantuml-syntax'
    Plug 'tyru/open-browser.vim'
    Plug 'weirongxu/plantuml-previewer.vim'

    au FileType plantuml let g:plantuml_previewer#plantuml_jar_path = get(
    \  matchlist(system('cat `which plantuml` | grep plantuml.jar'), '\v.*\s[''"]?(\S+plantuml\.jar).*'),
    \  1,
    \  0
    \)
```

I've run `:PlugInstall` (everything was installed), then I've saved `.vimrc`, closed and reran iTerm2.
I've created a `*puml` with content and start the preview with `:PlantumlOpen`.
Google Chrome get opened on `file:///Users/itsme/.vim/plugged/plantuml-previewer.vim/viewer/dist/index.html` but it shows only the PlantUML canvas without the diagram.

Does anybody see, what I've done wrong or has an idea where I can start to search what's going wrong?

Kind regards,
Manny

Comment: I strongly suspect you’ll get the best answer from the plugin maintainers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem (or takes deeper configuration at the end) with the Java installation of `homebrew install java`.
Choose the [Java installation file from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac) for the Java installation.